# espn api error from URI link

Tags: api, espn

I have just signed up to have access to espn api and I just want to access a specific teams data but an error message appears saying "timestamp" :"2014-04-06T22:36:39Z","message" :"Improper API URI","status" :"error","code" :404"". The link I'm putting in with my api key is "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/soccer/english-premier-league/arsenal?apikey=************". I know you need an id with the team but where do I get that from and I don't think the link recognizes 'english-premier-league'.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the online API testing tool at http://developer.espn.com/io-docs?

Enter your API Key, and then find the endpoint to try.  Note that not all endpoints are supplied via the dropdown boxes.

With a little detective work, I found what you might be looking for

http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/soccer/eng.1/teams/359?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: This has help out but espn doesn't let you have specific information